# How to make HTML5 Geolocation more accurate?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I've been playing with the HTML5 Geolocation options and noticed that the results can be a bit erratic and wondered if there was a way to get them more consistent.

I've been doing all of my tests on an iphone 5 and just using the standard getCurrentPosition code with enableHighAccuracy: true and enableHighAccuracy: false, but sometimes when I click the code to get my position on a Google map it is sometimes about 0.25-0.5 mile out - yet (and this is a biggie) if I go to the Maps app on the phone it moves around a bit and then gets my position bang on.

Is there something I can do to get the same level of accuracy?

Speaking of accuracy - what does the position.coords.accuracy command actually do or mean?  I've had a map position bang on where I am yet it says something like 1200 and I've had it show the pin about 400 yards away from my location and I get 165

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError,{maximumAge:600000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
} else {
x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}

function showPosition(position) {

 var x = document.getElementById("demo");

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat:position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude}, map: map, title: 'X'});

x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + "<br>Accuracy: " + position.coords.accuracy;
```

}

Apologies I'm new to posting in this forum.

Comment: Call Google, ask them to update their database so the accuracy gets better.

Comment: Sorry but what exactly does this have to do with html5?

Comment: @Victor - presumably, the OP is using the HTML Geolocation API

Comment: But I'm giving the Google Map the lat and long values via the GetPosition call.  The Maps app moves around a bit and then finds me, but my click it once Get Position call sometimes gives me a wild result.

Comment: What is the exact code you are using?

Comment: Victor, I'm under the impression that the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition call is a HTML5 one

Comment: that sounds like the device is giving the browser wild results - the browser itself has no idea where  you are, it depends on the device

Comment: What happens with the HTML5 API, is that it gathers information about nearby wireless access points and your computer/phone IP address. Then the browser sends this information to the default geolocation service provider, usually Google Location Services, to get an estimate of your location. That location estimate is then shared with the requesting website. The estimate is based on data kept in a database about cell phone towers, wireless networks etc, so most of the time it's just a guess.

Comment: you know, the code should be **in the question** so it can be at least half readable

Comment: However, when you plot latitude and longitude into a map, the location should be spot on ...

Comment: Ah, my bad, I did read geocoding for some arcane reason.

Comment: Anyway, Google is using additional (and frowned upon, and possibly illegal) practices (like tracking wifi hotspots' location via android devices) to "enhance" the location information, whilst regular browsers and devices without GPS have to rely on public information like geoip and public hotspot databases.

Comment: But surely the iphone using 4G type technology (??) to get and pass the location to Safari??

Comment: 4G has nothing to do with geolocation, but you'd think the browser has access to the GPS coordinates from your phone, and it does, but it doesn't always use it. Sometimes it will use the IP for location instead, as the GPS in your phone can be rather slow to respond, and by default `getCurrentPosition()` tries to answer as fast as possible with low accuracy. If you set the accuracy to `high` it should wait longer for the GPS coordinates, but not very long, so sometimes even that will use the IP adress. Where the limit is for how long it will wait, only the browser vendor knows.

Comment: As per my code example, I've tried enablehighaccuracy but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  I would have thought the browser uses the same tech as the maps app. Why would it be different???

Answer (score 0):

position.coords.accuracy is a measurement of meters. If you were to draw a circle around the Lat/Lng returned as its center and "accuracy as its radius then the UA suggests that your "real" location is in that circle somewhere.

enableHighAccuracy = true may remove mobile phone towers and wi-fi distribution points from the heuristic GPS calculation but I too am disappointed at the difference between a Chrome GPS mapped to Google Map as opposed to the Maps App. Also indoor readings could be few and far between if you go the accuracy route.

Experimenting with some algorithms where don't rely on it unless the accuracy is <= the last one (or until Xms or Y>accuracy readings have been received) may help.